# Kinect: Assign joint type to read only struct from existing coordinates (redraw skeleton from file)

Tags: c#, kinect

I tried to modify the JointType of the Joint class, here's section of the code:

```
Joint currentJoint = new Joint();
SkeletonPoint position = currentJoint.Position;
currentJoint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.NotTracked;
position.X = -1;
position.Y = -1;
position.Z = -1;

currentJoint.Position = position;
currentJoint.JointType = JointType.AnkleLeft;

if (_joint._jointType == "AnkleLeft")
    currentJoint.JointType = JointType.AnkleLeft;
if (_joint._jointType == "AnkleRight")
    currentJoint.JointType = JointType.AnkleRight;
if (_joint._jointType == "ElbowLeft")
```

I couldn't get this line `currentJoint.JointType = JointType.AnkleLeft;`to work, it says

> Joint.JointType' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

I tried like this:

```
JointType cjoint = currentJoint.JointType;
cjoint = JointType.AnkleLeft;
currentJoint.JointType = cjoint;
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make `JointType` non-readonly in your `Joint` class

Comment: Can I do that? It's the class in kinect.dll. I can't modify it.

Comment: Then it may be modified through a method than directly via the field.

Comment: Could you show me how, please? I'm quite new to this. Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably want to use an existing joint object instead of trying to create your own.

Comment: I tried to retrieve the data outside the joint object itself, let's say .txt file which contains all the information. Then assign all the information to its respective property.